# iPhone SDK: Advancing from one view to another using a button tap

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I want to make a really simple iphone app:  one screen with a single button... when the button is tapped a new screen appears.  That's it.  No animations, nothing,

I've tried endlessly to make the NavBar sample project do this... and it works but only if I use a UINavigationController with a table that I can tap etc.  I've tried all the skeleton projects in XCode too.

I thought I was done when I did this:

```
[[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

But I couldn't do it without the UINavigationController.  I just want a simple example.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way you could do this is to create a new UIView and then when the button is pressed add that new UIVIew as a subview, therefore making it what you see.

If you make the new view its own subclass of UIView you would do something like this.

```
LoginView *login = [[LoginView alloc] initWithFrame: rect];
[mainView addSubview: login];
```

Answer (score 6):

```
[self presentModalViewController:myViewController animated:NO];
```

Will pop up a new view, no animations, nothing. To get rid of it, inside myViewController:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Though I reccomend you use the nice sliding animations (change NO to YES.) And yes, you can stack them up. I think this is better than creating a new UIView, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is set up your project with a `UINavigationController`. In your root view controller, add your button in the view controllers's view. Then in `viewDidLoad`, register for `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` events from you button. Then, in your event callback, call:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:[[[SecondViewControllerClass alloc] initWithNib:nibName bundle:nil] autorelease]];
```

What kdbdallas suggested will work, but you won't get the nice sliding effects, nor will the navigation bar automatically change and provide your users with a back button.